# Web fragments with maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, servlet-filters, web-fragment

I've just discovered web fragments and I'd like to use them in my pluggable application. Basically I'm building a plugin which will contain the security part of my app (based on Spring security). The web fragment contains only the servlet filter:

```
<!-- Loads the security fragment first -->
<ordering>
    <before>
        <others />
    </before>
</ordering>

<!-- Spring security filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The problem is that it's not working at all. The filter works fine if I test it in the main app but if I put it here I'm not intercepting any call. I think it may be caused by the maven build. I'm packaging the project as a jar because I've read around to do so. The web-fragment.xml is under /bin/META-INF/.

Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: web-fragment must be located in `META-INF`, not `/bin/META-INF`

Comment: @michaldo Under project root? I've just tried and it's still not working.

Comment: Your project is JAR, so your output is JAR. Check your output file and find where web-fragment is located.

Comment: You are right. There's no web-fragment in the output file. It seems that maven puts it there only with the war packaging. The problem is that I can't do that since there's no web.xml...

Comment: You are wrong. I have maven, Jar project, web-fragment and all works. My fragment is located in `src\main\resources\META-INF\web-fragment.xml`

Comment: I was indeed wrong. Now it's working fine. If you want to write an answer I'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place your web-fragment in `src\main\resources\META-INF\web-fragment.xml`